# Google Sheets - =ISURL()

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In Google Sheets, I want check if a URL exists in the cell.

I do this with `=ISURL(E1)` which seems simple enough. I have this setup as a custom formula within Data Validation. The problem is, I want to do this for the entire column and I don't want to type `=ISURL(E1)`, `=ISURL(E2)`, `=ISURL(E3)`, etc... for every single row. This rule is only applied to itself, so is there a way I can make the cell reference itself? For example `=ISURL(SELF)`, then I can copy/paste this rule on the entire column?

I've tried the below but none work.

- `=ISURL()`
- `=ISURL(E$1)`
- `=ISURL(SELF)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data validation has a condition `Is Valid URL`.
You do not need a `custom formula`.

Also,

```
=ISURL(E1)
```

Apply to range `E1:E20`
Works well for the whole range.

Answer (score 0):

There's a build in function for that, you don't need to use a custom formula.

In the **`Data validation`** popup go to **`Criteria`** select **`Text`** and then **`is valid url`**.